# Cast a PostgreSQL row to text, but keep columns separate

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am working on a Postgres viewer using Python. I need to convert all columns to text so I can display them in my GUI. I don't know how many columns there are per table or the names of them as this is supposed to be a generic viewer. Google got me this code:

```
SELECT t.*::text FROM table AS t;
```

However, this concatenates the row like this:

```
t
----------------|-------
(712,982,dfdfv)
```

What I need is this (with type text of course), just like a normal `SELECT *` does:

```
id  | vendor_id | vendor_barcode
----|-----------|---------------
712 | 982       | dfdfv
```

Edit1: I can't convert the datatypes in Python, because a None will become a 'None'.

Edit2: I need the column names from cursor.description(), so I can't use t.*::text.

Comment: You could do it Python side something like: `rows = ([str(col) for col in row] for row in cursor.execute('select * from table'))` and then iterate over `rows`? Not sure if that's convenient for your use case though.

Comment: okay... so don't do that? Just `select * from table` ?

Comment: Then `rows = ([str(col) for col in row if col is not None else None] for row in cursor.execute('select * from table'))` possibly?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in postgres (although I'd love to be corrected) that allows you to say give me every column as text values conveniently...

Comment: One approach might be to use pandas w/ sqlalchemy and then you get the benefits of having a dataframe you can re-use if needs be and then do something like: `df = pandas.read_sql('table_name', engine).astype(str)`... that'd preserve your None's as NaNs...

Comment: @JonClements `rows = ([str(col) for col in row if col is not None else None] for row in c.fetchall())` gives me a syntax error pointing to `else`. Any suggestions? This syntax is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Yeah... sorry... long day and tired eyes... what I meant to say was: `rows = ([str(col) if col is not None else None for col in row] for row in c.fetchall())` - I'd also remove that `.fetchall()` - no need to retrieve the entire lot when you're going to iterate over it.

Comment: @JonClements Ok everything works now. It doesn't work to replace `.fetchall` with `.execute` though. I get : `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
`

Comment: I removed my extended comments to clean up. @JonClements If you post an answer I'll accept it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Oh... just execute on the cursor object then iterate then...

Comment: Feel free to post a self-answer that works for you... I'm not sure if I were to answer  this what'd be the points I've made that worked or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so one solution offered by @Jon Clements is:

```
 c = connection.cursor()
 c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")
 rows = (str(col) if col is not None else None for col in c.fetchall())
 for row in rows:
     print (row)
```

My final solution was:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1")
select_sql = "SELECT "
for row in c.description:
    column_name = row.name
    if type_ == 17: #binary data
        select_sql += " '<binary data>',"
    else:
        select_sql += " CASE WHEN %s::text='' THEN '''''' ELSE %s::text END," % (column_name, column_name)
select_sql = select_sql[:-1] + " FROM my_table" #remove trailing comma and add table name
c.execute(select_sql)
```

Which converts blank strings to `''` and preserves `None` values. My code is actually more extensive, because it needs to create treeview columns and etc. Hopefully this helps out anyone coming here in the future.